# How do I merge 2 rows into one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to merge these two records together? In the example below the `WARD_NUMBER` column is an identifier of a ward a patient would stay on.

Timeline is the patient came onto the ward at 10:10am and was discharged at 22:48 the same day. What we are seeing in the system is a bed transfer within the ward which is triggering this issue as this ISNT a ward transfer

What I wondered is it possible to show one row of data only (always retaining the 1st `WARD_STAY_IDENTIFIER` and `START_DATE_TIME_WARD_STAY` but merging to include the 2nd `END_DATE_TIME_WARD_STAY`

For example

```
('600054394373', '2018-01-05 10:10:00.000', '2018-01-05 22:48:49.000', '600007275916', '3400003723'),
```

TIA

```
DECLARE @CDI_APC_WARD_STAY TABLE (HOSPITAL_PROVIDER_SPELL_NUMBER  varchar(50),
                          START_DATE_TIME_WARD_STAY datetime, 
                          END_DATE_TIME_WARD_STAY datetime,
                          WARD_STAY_IDENTIFIER varchar(50),
                          WARD_NUMBER varchar(50)
                         )

INSERT INTO @CDI_APC_WARD_STAY
    VALUES 
    ('600054394373', '2018-01-05 10:10:00.000', '2018-01-05 11:50:00.000', '600007275916', '3400003723'),
    ('600054394373', '2018-01-05 11:50:00.000', '2018-01-05 11:54:00.000', '600007276481', '3400003723'),
    ('600054394373', '2018-01-05 11:54:00.000', '2018-01-05 20:22:00.000', '600007276510', '3400003723'),
    ('600054394373', '2018-01-05 20:22:00.000', '2018-01-05 20:23:00.000', '600007279380', '3400003723'),
    ('600054394373', '2018-01-05 20:23:00.000', '2018-01-05 22:48:49.000', '600007279385', '3400003723'),
    ('600054394373', '2018-01-05 22:48:49.000', '2018-01-06 20:24:04.000', '600007279710', '3400003688')
```

Comment: For the sample data, it's easy. But... do you have 3+ rows for the same patient stay? Multiple separate stays?

Comment: Yes apologies you can indeed, so say for example there were 6 bed transfers all on the same ward, as a ward stay I would need to take the first StartDate, Identifier and the last EndDate to show as a full Ward Stay.

Comment: What identifies the patient?    You should have more data an desired output.

Comment: There is a Patient Identifier elsewhere but for this the Hospital Provider Spell Number is unique to a patients stay in hospital weather it be 1 day or 1 year. The Ward Stay identifier is at a transaction level and unique to the this table, however its the Ward Number field repeating several times which isn't right given the table is for WARD STAYS and should only reflect start and end dates of the entire stay on the ward.

Comment: You still did not provide desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    c1.HOSPITAL_PROVIDER_SPELL_NUMBER,
    FirstDate = MIN(c1.START_DATE_TIME_WARD_STAY),
    LastDate = MAX(c2.END_DATE_TIME_WARD_STAY),
    WardStayID = MIN(c1.WARD_STAY_IDENTIFIER),
    c1.WARD_NUMBER
FROM
    @CDI_APC_WARD_STAY c1
    JOIN
    @CDI_APC_WARD_STAY c2 ON c2.HOSPITAL_PROVIDER_SPELL_NUMBER = c1.HOSPITAL_PROVIDER_SPELL_NUMBER
      AND c2.START_DATE_TIME_WARD_STAY = c1.END_DATE_TIME_WARD_STAY
      AND c2.WARD_NUMBER = c1.WARD_NUMBER
GROUP BY
    c1.HOSPITAL_PROVIDER_SPELL_NUMBER,
    c1.WARD_NUMBER;
```

Comment: I have edited the original post to highlight multiple records and the last one is to show yes it the same Hospital Spell but shows them finally moving onto another ward (WARD_NUMBER)

Comment: What should the sample data look like now?

Comment: Just edited the text in the post also and leaving for home now so will check in the morning (UK time)

Comment: Updated for new sample data

Comment: Thanks I will mark this as the answer as I gives me a great starting position, incidentally though it this now excludes all records (over 90% where are NOT any transfers at all eg just one records with a start/end  date, is there any way these can also be factored in??

Comment: Change "JOIN" to "LEFT JOIN", but we again that isn't in the sample output. I am guessing here...